Circulant determinant of even size - missing term
Circulant matrix of size $n$ over any commutative ring $\textbf{R}$ is following square matrix
$$
\mathscr{C}(c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots, c_{n-1}, c_n):= \begin{pmatrix}
  c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & \cdots & c_{n-1}  & c_n\\
  c_n & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_{n-2}  & c_{n-1}\\
  c_{n-1} & c_n & c_1 & \cdots & c_{n-3}  & c_{n-2}\\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & \cdots & c_1  & c_2\\
  c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & \cdots & c_n  & c_1\\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3 \dots , c_{n-1},c_n \in \textbf{R}$.
Basic informations about determinant of such matrix are here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantDeterminant.html.
I am interested in determinant terms of general circulant matrix of even size. Problem is independent on commutative ring so you could for simplicity consider just $\textbf{R}=\mathbb{R}$.
In following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06012 were circulant determinants deeply examined, however Corollary 1 was left as home exercise and I want help with finding as elementary proof as possible using just well known properties of permutations and determinants.
Reformulation of Corollary 1: Let $k$ be any $\textbf{even}$ number. Then $|\mathscr{C}(c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots, c_{k-1}, c_k)|$ has no term of the form $c_1c_2c_3 \dots c_{k-1}c_k$.
I tried to use induction and Laplace expansion for even sized circulant determinants, however it does not work. Well known formula for factored form of circulant determinant (based on finding eigenvalues of circulant matrix) from here https://yutsumura.com/determinant-of-a-general-circulant-matrix/ is maybe good tool.
To give you intuition let compute determinants of small order circulant matrices:
$$
|\mathscr{C}(a,b)|=a^2-b^2
$$
$$
|\mathscr{C}(a,b,c)|=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc
$$
$$
|\mathscr{C}(a,b,c,d)|=
a^4 - b^4 + c^4 - d^4 - 2 a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2 d^2 - 4 a^2 b d + 4 a b^2 c - 4 b c^2 d  + 4 a c d^2
$$
You could clearly see that $|\mathscr{C}(a,b,c)|$ has term of all variables $abc$ (even three times!), however determinants of ciruclant matrices of even size does not ($ab$ and $abcd$ are missing).
